# Wrapping a DLL import in a module in F#

Tags: f#, dllimport

I'm attempting to create a "wrapper" module for some windows api functions from `user32.dll`. I'm still learning F# so I'm rather fuzzy on how inheritance and polymorphism works in F# and how to apply that to this situation.

I have this module:

```
module MouseControl =         
    [<DllImport( "user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )>]
    extern void ShowCursor(bool show)

    [<DllImport( "user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )>]
    extern void internal mouse_event(int flags, int dX, int dY, int buttons, int extraInfo)
    let MouseEvent(flags, dX, dY, buttons, extraInfo) = mouse_event(flags, dX, dY, buttons, extraInfo)
```

My goal is to be able to "hide" the `mouse_event` function from other code that uses this module and instead expose that function as `MouseEvent`. With this code *both* `mouse_event` and `MouseEvent` are currently available to code that calls this module. How do I hide `mouse_event` where it's private to the module?

Comment: BTW: This is not related to polymorphism or inheritance in any way - so I removed the tag from your question. It is just about using visibility annotations...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code sample, you already marked the `mouse_event` function as `internal` - so in principle, you should just need to mark it as `private`. However, it looks that F# compiler is ignoring visibility annotations on `extern` members, so the easiest option is to put them in a nested module and hide the whole nested module:

```
module MouseControl =         
  module private Imported = 
    [<DllImport( "user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )>]
    extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dX, int dY, int buttons, int extraInfo)

  let MouseEvent(flags, dX, dY, buttons, extraInfo) = 
    Imported.mouse_event(flags, dX, dY, buttons, extraInfo)
```

The module `Imported` is now visible only inside the `MouseControl` module. From the outside, you cannot access anything inside `MouseControl.Imported`.